# group_concat returns empty when using HAVING x like '%%', but not with WHERE x like '%%'

Tags: mysql

In my example query below, I am pulling all text that matches a keyword and splitting results by year-month. I prefer to search on 'text' - the concated version of all strings, instead of just against each field with a WHERE clause, but HAVING does not return any data:

```
SELECT 
date_format(created_date, '%Y-%m') as yr_mo,
count(id),
group_concat(coalesce(title,''),coalesce(story,'') SEPARATOR ' ') as text
from input_form
where dupe = 0 /*and story like '%flood%'*/
group by yr_mo
having text like '%flood%'
order by yr_mo
```

Below is what gets returns when I uncomment /** and story like '%flood%' **/ and remove the HAVING clause:

```
yr_mo   count(id)   text
2011-04 2   Floods Roads in my  community one time proved to b...
2011-05 21  THE TRUSTED LADY.   It was during my usual visits ...
2011-06 22  HEAVY RAINFALL On our village we were affected wit...
2011-07 52  FEED THE CHILDREN PROGRAMME(1) The world food prog...
2011-08 29  I was saved and helped to prosperI am one of the v...
2011-09 15  FLOODS In the past three months the country have f...
2011-10 19  FLOODFlood is a very bad disaster at the same time...
2011-11 9   RESPONDING TO DISASASTERUNICEF landed over relief ...
2011-12 3   EARLY PREVENTION OF FLOODShaving sensed the likeli...
2012-01 44  HUNGER STRIKE             In Wataalamu village the...
2012-04 8   THE FALLEN BRIDGEThe Kambu bridge along the Mombas...
2012-05 7   Increasing earth's natural environment awarenessAf...
2012-06 4   A misery solvedRecently 10 people died in my commu...
2012-07 21  Lsot HopesWhen the Agricultural Farmers Society ca...
```

I've tried avoiding nulls with coalesce(story,'') but the result was the same.

EDIT #1: I found a longer and messier query to work, and provide me what I want:

```
SELECT 
date_format(created_date, '%Y-%m') as yr_mo,
count(if( ( story like '%hunger%' OR title like '%hunger%' ) and (story_location_city like '%nairobi%' OR story_location_neighborhood like '%nairobi%'),id,null)) as 'hunger',
count(if( ( story like '%poverty%' OR title like '%poverty%' ) and (story_location_city like '%nairobi%' OR story_location_neighborhood like '%nairobi%'),id,null)) as 'poverty',
count(if( ( story like '%school%' OR title like '%school%' ) and (story_location_city like '%nairobi%' OR story_location_neighborhood like '%nairobi%'),id,null)) as 'school',
count(id) as total
from input_form
where dupe = 0
group by yr_mo
order by yr_mo
```

If I must, I can search each field within an if() statement, and it will provide specific results. Is there no more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What about `COUNT(IF(MATCH(story) AGAINST('hunger poverty school' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))` ? You can add ` OR MATCH(title)...` to search all words in title or story. Note this works on MyISAM only and should have a FULLTEXT index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT` truncates its output to (by default) 1024 characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), so the `HAVING` clause requires that the string `flood` appear within the first 1024 characters of the concatenated text, whereas the `WHERE` clause merely requires that it appear *somewhere* in `input_form.story`.

Even if it weren't for the truncation, I think that `GROUP_CONCAT` + `HAVING` would not really be what you would want, since that would include *all* records for any month that had *any* matching record. For example, if April 2012 had twenty records, but only ten contained `flood`, then a `GROUP_CONCAT` + `HAVING` approach would (if not for the truncation) say that there were twenty matching records for April 2012, and would include text from all of them.

Comment: I've taken your comments and written an alternate approach that should only match records within each month that contain a keyword.

Comment: Your `COUNT(IF(...))` approach actually looks pretty good to me. But if you prefer, you can concatenate those fields using [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).